# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)

Tags: python, pip, aiohttp

When I try to install an aiohttp package with pip it drops me an error:

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1

I use python 3.8.5 and pip version 20.2.4. How can I fix this problem?

Full command output:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'd:\важности\websocket\venv\scripts\python.exe' 'd:\важности\websocket\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\a
lext\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp3maewxe3'
         cwd: C:\Users\alext\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fidr_740\yarl
    Complete output (23 lines):
    **********************
    * Accellerated build *
    **********************
    running dist_info
    creating C:\Users\alext\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-hcjz4pf4\yarl.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\alext\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-hcjz4pf4\yarl.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\alext\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-hcjz4pf4\yarl.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to C:\Users\alext\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-hcjz4pf4\yarl.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\alext\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-hcjz4pf4\yarl.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\alext\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-hcjz4pf4\yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\alext\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-hcjz4pf4\yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.cache' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.html'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.so'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\*.pyd'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\alext\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-hcjz4pf4\yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    creating 'C:\Users\alext\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-hcjz4pf4\yarl.dist-info'
    error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'd:\важности\websocket\venv\scripts\python.exe' 'd:\важности\websocket\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_met
adata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\alext\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp3maewxe3' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: The information seems to be in the error message " (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)" but we have no idea what this file contains.

Comment: Does it really have a misspelling in "accelerated"?

Comment: Note that there is also another error in the message "error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'" which probably means that the `wheel` package is not installed, i.e. you need to `pip install wheel`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, it is my fault as the library author.

Should be fixed by https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/5230 and the new aiohttp bugfix release.